# Convert string to specific datetime/Timezone

Tags: powershell, datetime, timezone

Using Powershell, How can I convert this string to US Eastern/Time and just display the time using format `HH:mm:ss` ?

```
Thu, 30 Nov 2023 17:50:51 GMT
```

Any help is appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeBySystemTimeZoneId` Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timezoneinfo.converttimebysystemtimezoneid?view=net-8.0):

```bash
[System.TimeZoneInfo]::ConvertTimeBySystemTimeZoneId(
    [System.DateTimeOffset] 'Thu, 30 Nov 2023 17:50:51 GMT',
    'Eastern Standard Time').
    ToString('HH:mm:ss')
```

As aside, when you're not sure what's the `Id` you should use for the `destinationTimeZoneId` argument, you can use:

```bash
[System.TimeZoneInfo]::GetSystemTimeZones() |
    Select-Object DisplayName, Id, BaseUtcOffset
```

Comment: This method works excellent Santiago.  Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to format dates in PowerShell is to use the `ToString()` method. This method allows you to convert a date object to a string representation using a specific date format.

For example, if you had a `DateTime` object representing January 1st, 2022, and you wanted to convert it to a string in the format “yyyy/MM/dd”, you could use the following command:

```
1
2
$Date = Get-Date "01/01/2022"
$Date.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd")
```

This would return the string “2022/01/01”.